# How to prevent addToBackStack when adding a fragment through xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to call a fragment from xml file but I do not want to add this fragment to the backstack. I went through many of the solutions but was not able to resolve the issue. I will be happy if I will get an appropriate solution for this query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement as to why you want this in the xml ?

Comment: A `Fragment` statically declared in your layout XML cannot be removed/replaced dynamically. That is, it's not even really involved in the back stack.

Comment: Then why dont you add that fragment views instead of fragment in activity.
you can override onbackpressed method and check count of fragments in fragment manager if(count==1)super.onbackpressed();else popbackstack